# JQuery Autocomplete caching with ajax not populating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

I am trying to add caching via ajax call to the below code.  The Code works fine with out caching, after I add the caching the first time the autocomplete works, the second time it just shows blank.  What am I doing wrong here?

My code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MainContent_txtSurname").autocomplete({

        source: function (request, response) {
            var term = request.term;
            if (term in cache) {
                response(cache[term]);
                return;
            }
            $.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,
                type: 'POST',
                url: "http://localhost:1448/GetSurnames",

                dataType: 'json',
                data: { "Name": request.term, "CID": CID },
                processdata: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    var Surnames = JSON.parse(result.data);

                    cache[term] = Surnames;
                    response($.map(Surnames, function (item) {

                        return {
                            label: item.homename,
                            value: item.homename
                        }
                    }));
                },
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    debugger;
                }
            });

        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

The data returned is:

```
{"data":"[{\"id\":3,\"homename\":\"D\\u0027Costa\"}]"}
```

Comment: Do you get any error with the `cache` variable ? Is it still blank if you type an other string ?

Comment: Don't you have to return as the response the same as the result of the map function?

Comment: I did not get any error with the 'cache' variable, if I type any other string or I continue typing after 3 letters the ajax call fires again and populates.  What I think is the it is not populating for the cache.

Comment: @JonathanNaguin now sure what you mean by that.  I am not too strong in javascript :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with caching the correct format data for the autocomplete plugin. On your Ajax success:

```
success: function (result) {
    var Surnames = JSON.parse(result.data);

    cache[term] = $.map(Surnames, function (item) {

        return {
            label: item.homename,
            value: item.homename
        }
    });
    response(cache[term]);
}
```